# How to use Linux headers on Windows using Cygwin?

Tags: c++, linux, cygwin, cross-compiling

After installing Cygwin, I have found all the tools to my satisfaction in the proper directories. But I can't figure out how to compile C++ code using headers like mman.h and dlfcn.h which are Linux specific headers ?

Comment: Cygwin provides the Posix APIs but is not Linux.

Comment: Maybe you want Linux hosted on Windows, using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)?  (I think both Cygwin and WSL are excellent facilities for Windows, and complementary, serving different purposes.)

Comment: Windows 8.1 doesn't support WSL and that's the OS I am using.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search in [cygwin package index](https://cygwin.com/packages/) reports `mman.h`  in the core [cygwin-devel](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/cygwin-devel.html) package and `dlfcn.h` in [mingw64-x86_64-dlfcn](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/mingw64-x86_64-dlfcn.html) package.

Comment: Yeah, but when I include them in the code and compile with gcc in a Cygwin terminal, I get errors.

Comment: What kind of errors? "cannot open file" or some expected functionality is not available or something else?

Comment: Thanks, it got resolved. I had not restarted my Cygwin terminal after updating the packages ;)